# Handling data between difference files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have 2 log files names `Attendance` and `Position`. I want to get position of the all the soldiers who were present (**YES**). How do i do this between these two files.

**Attendance File**

[image]

**Position File**

[image]

I thought of using `grep` to get the present name of soldiers. But then how to i proceed to get their position from another file.

Comment: Are your file image files? If not, consider including them as text in the question.  Also, since the data seems to mention army units, timestamps and locations, could you please confirm that this is indeed public data?

Comment: Yes it is text file. And the data is randomly generated.

Comment: Don't positions move between 0:00h and 6:00h?

Comment: I don't know about that. Anyways that wont matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *`diff`* command to compare two files in linux. This should work for what you need based on your description.

```
diff -y Attendance Position | grep YES > newfile
```

This will display both files side by side, displaying only lines with YES, and send the output to *newfile*

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: Yaa i used the command you gave and the awk command to get only the coordinates. Thanks for the hep

Comment: Excellent. Hopefully you have some additional tools at your disposal the next time you need to work in bash.

Comment: Yaa sure. I'll visit this site whenever there's a prob

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right, `grep` first for all soldiers with Yes-attribute. Then extract name with `awk` and stuff into array or second `grep`. Extracting the names is not so complicated (assuming filename is Attendance):

```
<Attendance grep 'Yes' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Now it depends on how large the result set is. If this yields <50 names to lookup you could simply put the result as parameters to a next grep on Position-file. If there are way more, exceeding the number of command line parameters being supported by your shell, write a small (Bash-) script. Put chunks of names into an array and loop over all the lines read in to find matches.

With >10.000 log entries operate block wise like so (also incorporating the other comments, as a Bash script file):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A position

# build up a hash table through preformatted Bash-statements
while read i; do
    eval "$i"
done < <(awk '{print "position['\''"$2"'\'']='\''"$3"'\''"}' Position)

echo "read ${#position[@]} positions"

# Lookup positions from the hash table
while read name; do
    pos="${position[$name]}"
    if [ -z "$pos" ]; then
        pos="-"
    fi
    echo "$name $pos"
done < <(awk '/YES/ { print $2 }' Attendance)
```

This will not work correctly when your name contains spaces, e.g. to split surname and name, titles, ranks and such. Since you need more attributes and also some sort of distance and time approximation – maybe not every soldier has a the exact position for a given timestamp – I suggest to pay a developer.

You could also extend the key-attribute for the hash table *position* to store and later lookup entries.

Comment: Don't combine `grep` with `awk`. Instead: `awk '/YES/ { print $2 }' Attendance`.  However, if a unit's name contains the string `YES`, this would be pulled out too (you have the same issue in your pipeline).

Comment: You're absolutely right in case there's a deep understanding of awk. I'd say it is easier to build atop existing knowledge and deepen afterwards…which is happening right now. The entire task could be solved with a single pass with a filter and a associative array by an expert. I prefer to only assist.

Comment: The entire log file contains 15000 entires. So its a big data to handle. Can you explain a method to do the last two lines of your answer. I mean looping over all lines to find matches

Comment: Also i need both date and name for soldiers with YES coz then only I''' get their exact position.

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
grep YES file1 | cut -f2 -d" " | grep -f- file2
```

Comment: This will give all the positions of the soldiers for a specific date. Coz you have taken the date column as pattern for the next grep. And also the time varies in both files so i grep won't work directly

Comment: Better would be to get the date and name form the attendance file and use `grep` in the position file. I am thinking of storing the date and name is sep variables to carry out smoothly

Comment: Sorry, I `cut` the wrong field as due to missing sample data I had to create my own sample. Corrected in post. Pls try again.